# dvc exp run --queue unexpected error 'utf-8'

Tags: sqlite, utf-8, dvc

ML python project pipeline works with

- dvc repro
- dvc exp run

but I can't put exp in queue
dvc exp run --queue
ERROR: unexpected error - 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xc4 in position 28: invalid continuation byte

And this is full tracebcak.

dvc==2.37.0

sqlite=3.38.5=h8ffe710_0

part of dvc.yaml

```
train:
    foreach: ${model_training.pools}
    do:
      cmd: >
        python pipeline_scripts/train.py
        --data_dir ${general.data_dir}
        ${item.train}
      deps:

      params:
        - general.data_dir
      outs:
        - models/=${item.train.model_name}
        - data/train_data/prediction.pickle.gz
      metrics:
        - metrics//metrics.json:
            cache: false
        - metrics//metrics_volatility.json:
            cache: false
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I changed my Windows settings and it works!
Helped answer @Isti115
https://superuser.com/questions/269818/change-default-code-page-of-windows-console-to-utf-8

I just copied it here:

In the 1809 build of Windows 10 I've managed to permanently solve this by going to the system's Language settings, selecting Administrative language settings, clicking Change system locale... and checking the Beta: Use Unicode UTF-8 for worldwide language support box and then restarting my pc.

[image]

This way it applies to all applications, even those ones that I don't start from a command prompt!
(Which was necessary for me, since I was trying to edit Agda code from Atom.)

Windows screenshot - Region Settings - UTF-8